# Payment method does not appear in Store > Configuration > Sales > Payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Payment method does not appear in Store > Configuration > Sales > Payment method

I have (I think succesfully) created a custom payment method.

My custom method is shown in the list when i check with

```
    // payment methods with detail
    $allPaymentMethods = $this->paymentHelper->getPaymentMethods();
    // payment methods list array
    $allPaymentMethodsArray = $this->paymentHelper->getPaymentMethodList();
    var_dump($allPaymentMethodsArray);
```

Bu when I go to admin I can't see the method.

Is it normal ? If not what is wrong and if it is what should I do to make it appear in the admin page with all the others payment methods ?

I followed this guide to create the payment method : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-payment-method/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to confirm following things.

1. Confirm you are creating `all required file` for the extension.
2. Extension is `install` properly.
3. Extension is enable into `config.php` file.
4. You are creating the proper `system.xml` file.

Comment: I do not have any system.xml (I have module / config / payment xml).

Comment: Oh I just see the explanation wasn't giving all the files. I will try to see with the archive and see what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: Adding the system.xml is the solution !